# Pandas multi-index best way to slice for ranges of subordinate levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two questions concerning pandas dataframe multi-indices.

Assume I have a data-frame df as follows:

```
                                   data
    port                           bm  pf
    sector instrument date
    1      A          2013-01-14    0   0
                      2013-01-15    5   5
                      2013-01-16   10  10
                      2013-01-17   15  15
                      2013-01-18   20  20
```

Which can be generated with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
date = pd.bdate_range('2013-01-14','2013-01-20').repeat(5)
sector = [1,1,1,2,2] * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(port=['pf']*25,sector=sector,instrument=list('ABCDE')*5,date=date,data=xrange(25)))
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(dict(port=['bm']*25,sector=sector,instrument=list('ABCDE')*5,date=date,data=xrange(25)))],axis=0)
df = df.set_index(['port','sector','instrument','date'])
df = df.unstack('port')
```

I want to get two sets of results: all the values on 2013-01-17 and all the values from 2013-01-17 to the end of the series.

For the first I know I can use one of the following approaches:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
targetdate = pd.Timestamp('2013-01-17')
slicer = (slice(None),slice(None),targetdate)
```

1) `df.loc[slicer,:]`

2) `df.xs(pd.Timestamp('2013-01-17'),level=2)`

3) `df.xs(slicer,)`

4) `df[idx[:,:,targetdate],:]`

all of which seem quite clunky. Is there a more obvious way I'm missing? What other ways are there to acheive this. I guess I'm hoping there is something like `df.loc(level=2)[targetdate]` (which doesn't work of course).

For the second I've only come up with one solution

```
query = df.index.get_level_values(2) >= pd.Timestamp('2013-01-17')
df[query]
```

Again is there a more efficient way to do this?

Final bonus question: what does `df.index.get_loc_level()` do? I feel like it should help with this but I have no idea how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this masking, like you're doing, is going to be pretty good here:

```
query = df.index.get_level_values(2) >= pd.Timestamp('2013-01-17')
df[query]
```

if you have lots of repetition in dates you may improve performance with something lower-level:

```
query = (df.index.levels[2] >= pd.Timestamp("2013-01-17"))[df.index.labels[2]]
df[query]
```

*I'll probably get shouted out for that...! But it will be significantly faster in some cases.*

---

`get_loc_level` is the similar of loc, i.e. label based rather than by position:

> Get integer location slice for requested label or tuple

```
In [21]: df.index.get_loc_level(2)
Out[21]:
(slice(15, 25, None),
 MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E'], [2013-01-14 00:00:00, 2013-01-15 00:00:00, 2013-01-16 00:00:00, 2013-01-17 00:00:00, 2013-01-18 00:00:00]],
            labels=[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
            names=[u'instrument', u'date']))
```

by default it takes the first index, but you can pass in more...

```
In [21]: df.index.get_loc_level((1, "A"))
Out[21]:
(slice(0, 5, None), <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
 [2013-01-14, ..., 2013-01-18]
 Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy could I just check if you have any thoughts on the first question? Are there more efficient ways to pick items from the date index other than the four I've described above? .. and thanks for explaining the get_loc_level. Do you any use case examples you could share. Where might I apply it?

Comment: @TahnoonPasha tbh I consider get_loc_level nearly private/low-level, I prefer to use `xs` (cross section) which I think better describes the functionality. With regards to efficiency, __try__ a large frame/example with `%timeit` - I suspect my second line will be fastest (it was in a test I did, though I didn't try all your permutations).